# Virtual base members not seeing overrides?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I always thought `base.Something` was equivalent to `((Parent)this).Something`, but apparently that's not the case.  I thought that overriding methods eliminated the possibility of the original virtual method being called.

Why is the third output different?

```
void Main() {
    Child child = new Child();

    child.Method();             //output "Child here!"
    ((Parent)child).Method();   //output "Child here!"
    child.BaseMethod();         //output "Parent here!"
}

class Parent {
    public virtual void Method() { 
        Console.WriteLine("Parent here!"); 
    }
}

class Child : Parent {
    public override void Method() { 
        Console.WriteLine ("Child here!"); 
    }
    public void BaseMethod() { 
        base.Method(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in `BaseMethod` you *explicitly* call the method in the base class, by using the `base` keyword. There is a difference between calling `Method()` and `base.Method()` within the class.

In the documentation for the [`base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/hfw7t1ce(en-us).aspx) keyword, it says (amongst other things) that it can be used to *Call a method on the base class that has been overridden by another method*.

Answer (score 3):

`((Parent)this).foo` for virtual method foo is still/always a virtual method call.  The target address will be looked up from the class's virtual method table, which will always land you at the most derrived implementation for the type of the object instance.  You can cast it to parent all you want, but that doesn't change the vtable used to dispatch the call at runtime.

The `base` keyword makes the call resolve as a non-virtual call, so that you can reach the ancestor implementation from within a descendant implementation.  There is no address lookup at runtime, the address is resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

C# Language specification:

> At compile-time, *base-access*
>   expressions of the form base.I and
>   base[E] are evaluated exactly as if
>   they were written ((B)this).I and
>   ((B)this)[E], where B is the base
>   class of the class or struct in which
>   the construct occurs.
>
> When a *base-access* references a
>   virtual function member (a method,
>   property, or indexer), the
>   determination of which function member
>   to invoke at run-time (§7.4.4) is
>   changed. The function member that is
>   invoked is determined by finding the
>   most derived implementation (§10.6.3)
>   of the function member with respect to
>   B (instead of with respect to the
>   run-time type of this, as would be
>   usual in a non-base access).

I.e. base.Something is equivalent to ((Parent)this).Something but only for **non-virtual** members otherwise semantics is different.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you misunderstand `base.Something()`.  `base` specifically calls the base classes (possibly) overriden implementation of a method or property.  [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx):

> The base keyword is used to access
>   members of the base class from within
>   a derived class:
>
> Call a method on the base class that
>   has been overridden by another method.has been overridden by another method.

Note that `((Parent)this).Something()` would only affect what is called if you used `new` to hide a method instead of `override` a virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Casting the child as type of parent does not change the functions that are going to be called because they've been overridden on the object.  That's part of the beauty of inheritance (polymorphism).

In the BaseMethod you call base.Method, which is a way of getting access to the parent function (if you need it) but if you have an array of type Shape and in it are different subclasses of shape, you want the .Draw() method to call the subclass not the superclass method (by default).

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with understanding polymorphism.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism